# Pivoting a table in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query regarding pivoting a table with the following structure and data

Structure

Column Name Data Type
EMP_NAME    VARCHAR2(30)

DT  NUMBER(2,0)

PRESENT VARCHAR2(1)

EMP_NAME    DT  PRESENT

```
V   1   Y
V   2   Y
V   3   Y
V   4   Y
R   1   N
R   2   Y
R   3   Y
R   4   N
K   1   Y
K   2   Y
K   3   Y
K   4   N
```

I would like to pivot this table to display the name on the left , date on the top and the present in the centre (more like an attendance sheet). I got a code off the internet but that dint really help me. Please help..

Expected Output::

Name  1   2  3  4  5  6 7 8 9 10 11 12.......

R     y y n y ......

V    n y y n ......

K    y y y y ....

The number of names can grow and the data range for dt column will be from 1-31.

Thanks in advance

Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, but you need to know the number of values beforehand.
The assumption here is that 'Y' > 'N'.

Also note, that if in fact table some value is missing, like there is no record for some date then **MAX** function will return null. You should then surround it with **NVL** clause.

```
  select EMP_NAME
        ,max(a1) as a1
        ,max(a2) as a2
        ,max(a3) as a3
        ...
    from (select EMP_NAME
                ,decode(DT, '1', Present) as a1
                ,decode(DT, '2', Present) as a2
                ,decode(DT, '3', Present) as a3
                ...
            from test)
group by EMP_NAME
order by EMP_NAME;
```

Comment: Thxx a lot @Skoffer... U made my day sir/madam  !! Hats Off !!